# how to view my AMP webpages in the AMP mode on mobile

Tags: html, amp-html, google-web-designer

Normally, html pages can be tailored according to our needs and modify them and then view them. But in case of AMP webpages, even if my pages are showing no error upon AMP validation, is there anyway to see how it renders if it is ever delivered in AMP form? Usually Google serves highest ranked pages among its search result...and only that includes some AMP links. But if my site is not ranked high, can i still view my AMP pages in a way Google would render them for AMP in mobile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

-Run Test by typing your url

-Preview button appears if your site gets validated

-Clicking on it will take you to preview search results

-Your cached AMP site  will appear clicking on the amp search result